# regular expression to check presence of two distinct group of characters in string

Tags: regex

If I wish to check if any string starts with Europe, I can do the following using regular expression..

```
Europe[/s/S]*
```

But if I wish to check if a string starts with Europe and somewhere in the string also has England, how do I do the same..

I want the string

'Europe has England in it' to match

But,

'Europe has Germany in it' to not match

I tried unsuccessfully the below one.

```
Europe[/s/S]*England[/s/S]*
```

Comment: It's not `/s` and `/S`  but `\s` and `\S`

Comment: Use a backslash instead `[\s\S]*`. If you don't want to cross newlines, you could match both using `.*` and use word boundaries `^Europe\b.*\bEngland\b.*$`  https://regex101.com/r/qnX6qx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *positive lookahead*:

`^Europe.*(?=England).*$`

This will match any string that begins with "Europe" and has "England" in it.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EH6cNE/1)

Comment: Thanks, perfectly works.. but what happens if England has to be changed to ?England.. just trying to understand

Comment: @Arnab Are you using '?' literally? Because in regex it means "zero or one of" the preceding character.

Comment: yes, literally, if my requirement was '?England', is there any escape characters that can be used or something to accomodate the ?

Comment: Here you go: https://regex101.com/r/EH6cNE/2 Backslash is the escape character to be used.